# Is setup and loop provided for convenience?

Tags: programming, c++

Arduino sketches usually feature a [`setup`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Setup) and [`loop`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Loop) function. Are these functions only provided for convenience or do they actually have special purposes? (e.g.: are some operations disallowed or allowed in setup and loop)

Are these two pieces of code equivalent:

**Classic**

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

**Without loop**

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

    while(true) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        delay(1000);
    }
}


void loop() {
}
```

Is it possible to write code without either setup or loop, providing, for example, a `main` method or other entry point?

Answer (score 10):

Those pieces of code are pretty much the same.

If you look at the [Arduino source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L43-L48) you'll see:

```
setup();

for (;;) {
  loop();
  if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
}
```

(I'm not sure what `serialEventRun()` does.)

I don't think you can 'overload' the `main` function declaration. Also note that the main function calls `init`, which e.g. configures the timers, so `millis()` etc. will work.

Answer (score 9):

> Are these functions only provided for convenience or do they actually have special purposes?

The Arduino libraries do a tiny bit of housekeeping with `loop()`, related to [serial handling](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent).

> Are these two pieces of code equivalent:

Only if you never use serial events.

> Is it possible to write code without either setup or loop, providing, for example, a main method or other entry point?

Not while strictly using the Arduino libraries via the IDE; the linker will complain of either duplicate `main` definitions or of missing `setup` or `loop` definitions.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to write code without either setup or loop, providing, for example, a main method or other entry point?

The last time I used the IDE, you could have a project with no `.ino`/`.pde` file, only `.cpp`files; since it's the mangling of the `.ino` into a `.cpp` that defines the `main` function, if you bypass that step then you can define your own `main`.

If the IDE no longer allows this (as I've heard) you can still do the same thing with e.g. a Makefile-based build outside the IDE, without giving up the Arduino libraries. The caveats that I know of are:

- You should `#include "Arduino.h"` if you want access to the library functions.
- You should call `init()` if you want the library to set up peripherals the way you're used to.
- You should put the `serialEvent` code that Gerben points out in your mainloop if you want a `serialEvent` handler to run (but you probably don't need this anyway if you want to write your own mainloop).

Answer (score 1):

> Arduino sketches usually feature a setup and loop function. Are these functions only provided for convenience or do they actually have special purposes?

They throw in an extra function call to `init` which initializes the timers which let `millis`, `micros` and `delay` work without further effort. Other than that, no.

This code compiles (and runs) under the IDE:

```
int main ()
  {
  }
```

Effectively the IDE generates code like this:

```
int main ()
  {
  init ();  // set up timers
  setup (); // your own initialization
  while (true)
    loop ();  // stuff you want to keep doing
  }
```

They have fiddled with it since then, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, but basically you can ignore that. There is nothing particularly special about `setup` and `loop`.

You can use `main` like I showed above. You can do everything in `setup` if you want. You can do everything in `loop` if you want (if you never return from it).

Remember, you are dealing with a C++ compiler here. Functions don't have some magic significance based on their names.